# Search Functionality for a dynamic webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I have a webpage with multiple images loaded using a JSON File with schema something like -

```
[
{ "item" : "Lotus",
   "images" : [ "images/lotus1.jpg", "images/lotus2.jpg", "images/lotus3.jpg" ]
 },
 { "item" : "Tulip",
   "images" : [ "images/tulip1.jpg", "images/tulip2.jpg", "images/tulip3.jpg" ]
 }
....
]
```

If I want to add a search functionality on the page and dynamically show only the relevant images.

for eg. If a user wants to search for a particular flower and enters search text as "Tu", images with name having the search text should be displayed.

What technique, libraries or procedure I can follow? Is it possible to handle this only through front end or Does this percolate till the back end?

Any pointers are really appreciated!

Comment: for eg. If a user enters a search text as "tu", all images having "tu" in the name should be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to read this page http://api.jquery.com/find/ and try

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to display all the images on one page and let the [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/filtering.html) plugin take care of the filtering.
Here is a link to the [docs on filtering](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/filtering.html).
As a bonus it comes with fancy CSS effects, which make sorting a real pleasure ;)

You can find the code which addresses filtering by typing in a search field [here](http://forrst.com/posts/isotope_js_keyword_based_filtering-V6K).

It basically works by adding the names of your images as class names, showing only the ones that match your search while hiding the other classes.

However, if you have to deal with large amounts of images, this might not be an ideal solution, as all the images are loaded in advance to make this work. In this case, server side handling of the search would be the way to go.

**Edit**
[Here](https://github.com/desandro/isotope/issues/107) is another example on how to filter with a search field and isotope.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is with the back end. You should have your server return a json file with only relevant images, then your client side doesn't have to process that, and it could even be cached.

Otherwise client side it would just be an issue of looping through all the image "items", and searching for the query with `.indexOf` in the name. However, this would put a lot more work on your client side and probably make your site slower.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to keep it all in the front-end, you can use underscore.js. There are ways to filter through a array/object, see: http://underscorejs.org/#filter. You would query using regex to match against all the item names, example:

```
var images = [{ "item" : "Lotus", "images" : [ "images/lotus1.jpg", "images/lotus2.jpg", "images/lotus3.jpg" ]},{ "item" : "Tulip","images" : [ "images/tulip1.jpg","images/tulip2.jpg", "images/tulip3.jpg" ]}];
var searchResults = _.filter(images, function(obj){ return /lot/i.test(obj.item) });
```

This would return an object, with only the lotus, and all of the images needed. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cbM5W/1/

This does use the underscore library, but you could implement this with vanilla JS.